# magento 2 : how get the list of themes in my magento site?

Tags: magento2, module, theme

I want all information about  the theme in my module code how can I grab the theme information.The Theme that I have in my Magento like WordPress we can get all the themes information is it possible here.

This example is useful for magento 1.X what about magento 2.

Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageList();
Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getThemeList();

Comment: this is a bit unclear. What information you want about the theme? Give an example

Comment: @Marius I want theme name and version and all this and i want this info in my module

Comment: i want to do same thing in magento 2

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but since I was looking for the same thing, for future visitors:

```
use Magento\Framework\View\Design\Theme\ListInterface;

...

public function __construct(
    ListInterface $themeList
) {
    $this->themeList = $themeList;
}

public function getThemes()
{
    foreach ($this->themeList as $theme) {
        /** @var \Magento\Theme\Model\Theme $theme */
        // do things
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**If Someone needs to get the theme id from theme Name, use below**

```
 use \Magento\Theme\Model\ResourceModel\Theme\CollectionFactory;
...

 

    private $themeCollection;
    
        /**
         * Theming constructor.
         * @param Context $context
         * @param CollectionFactory $themeCollection
         */
        public function __construct(
            Context $context,
            CollectionFactory $themeCollection
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->themeCollection = $themeCollection;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param $themeName
         * @return int
         */
    
        public function getThemeId($themeName)
        {
            $collection = $this->themeCollection->create();
            $collection->addFieldToFilter('theme_path', $themeName);
            if ($collection->getSize() > 0) {
                return $collection->getFirstItem()->getThemeId();
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```